# can not resolve org.jetbrains.android

Tags: intellij-plugin, android-studio-plugin

Building an Android Studio Plugin using intellij and gradle as dependency management and trying to specify supported intelliJ IDE's

```
<depends>org.jetbrains.android</depends>
```

Issue is org.jetbrains.android is not resolved.

A suggested solution is :

you need to add plugins/android/lib/android.jar to the classpath of your IntelliJ IDEA SDK

can't find `plugins/android/lib/android.jar` . Any info on how I can locate this ?

Answer (score 3):

**Where is plugins/android/lib/android.jar?**

accord to [Dmitry Jemerov](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206110129-How-to-write-code-for-Android-Plugin):

> The jars of the Android plugin are part of the IntelliJ IDEA Community
>   Edition distribution ("plugins/android/lib" under the installation
>   directory). To use them in your plugin, you need to add them to the
>   classpath of the IntelliJ IDEA SDK, and also add this to your
>   plugin.xml:

```
<depends>org.jetbrains.android</depends>
```

For mac user :
you can find it in your application content
[image]

**How to the classpath of your IntelliJ IDEA SDK?**

[image]

[image]
[image]

just find android.jar in this plugin folder and add it to classpath.
Dont forget to add org.jetbrains.android to your plugin.xml

Answer (score 2):

The jar is in your Intellij installed directory (in plugins folder).

For me, a mac user the position is
**/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/android.jar**